# how to resize an embedded view in storyboard

Tags: swift, uiview, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

currently using iOS 8 and swift to create some apps. I am going to implement a game in a navigation-based app.

I am trying to resize an embedded view in storyboard. Since I have a navigation bar on top. when I run my app, the view blocks the navigation bar. How can I resize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode: Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller

Using this method, the navigation bar can show up again. However, not the same size as expected.